# Create a data tier in legacy C# application

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, n-tier-architecture

Subjective question I know....

We have an existing application that has around 20 components that connect to a database.  We are now clustering the application to increase scalability but we're hitting some limits where every process having a small connection pool is resulting in many connections to the DB.  There would also be some interesting options for caching across our cluster if we could centralise connections.

My question is are there any low cost/risk options to refactor our solution from utilising SQL connections directly to a middle tier?  Is the pain of this worth rewriting a full unit of work + models style application tier and refactoring all our database connections into the WCF business logic calls?

Answer (score 0):

As a longer term solution refactoring to a middle tier would be helpful in that any common connection handling logic can be centralized. One common reason for the multiple connection problem is that connections are not disposed of correctly but it's speculation without looking at the code.

See the following from the sql support team for diagnosing multiple connection issues http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_pfe_blog/archive/2013/10/08/connection-pooling-for-the-sql-server-dba.aspx

Comment: We have processes that are isolated for security and graceful failure.  You cannot share DB connections between processes and you can't share them between computers.  That's why we need to look at a data/application tier to meet this problem.

Comment: I was thinking of connection pooling at the sql server itself